# BatchNorm vs InstNorm from the perspective of feature distributions

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, normalization, batch-normalization

### What I understand so far...

The main purpose of BatchNorm is to overcome covariance shift -- more specifically what the authors of BatchNorm coined "internal covariance shift".

Covariance shift is a difference in **distribution of features** between the training dataset and inference dataset. But this **distribution of features** actually is a **metadistribution**: if you view a single data point as a distribution of features, then the covariance shift is describing the difference in **distribution of distribution of features**. The fact that instance normalization worked makes me think that this view is more accurate, because what instance normalizatoin does is normalize the distribution of features within a single instance, not amongst all other instances within a batch (which is what BatchNorm does).

### Question:

The potentially pedantic description of describing **distribution of features** as **meta distribution** was leading up to this question: it makes intuitive sense that normalizing features of all instances within a single batch can help covariance shift, since it is directly normalizing the **meta-distribution**. Then, what is it the implication of normalizing every individual distribution within the meta-distribution (i.e. InstNorm) in terms of covariance shift? I simply don't know enough about stats to predict the behavior of distribution of distribution, when each distribution within the meta-distribution is normalized.

I understand that my question isn't really well formed and explained, so I will fix it if you point out the obscurities.